# ajax send 2d array to action method error - asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

i want to send 2d array from javascript file to action method.
My javascript function

```
function _tbdata() {

var dataarr = [];

for(var i = 0; i<svarr.length; i++)
{
    var trangthai = $("input[name='" + svarr[i] + "']:checked").val();
    var lydo = $("#" + svarr[i]).val();
    dataarr[i] = new Array(2);
    dataarr[i][0] = trangthai;
    dataarr[i][1] = lydo;
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/DiemDanh/testMethod',
    data: { info: JSON.stringify(dataarr ) },
    type: "POST",
    traditional:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('running');
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }
});
}
```

And my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult testMethod(List<List<string>> info)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And when i debug in chrome, i got error

> POST http://localhost:56602/DiemDanh/testMethod 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

Sorry about my Enligsh is bad, Hope suggest from everybody!!!

Comment: Expand the response tab of the call and you will see the details of the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your javascript. Two dimensional array sholud be [[]]

I've write an example for your code. It works fine.

```
function Test() {
        var dataarr = [[]];

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            dataarr[i][0] = "A" + i.toString();
            dataarr[i][1] = "B" + i.toString();
        }

        var model = JSON.stringify(dataarr);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/testMethod',
            data: model,
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('running');
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i tried, but still error. I try debug, when function run to $.ajax, it throught error. i can't debug in ajax code.

Comment: Ajax is a jquery method. This code works fine in my local . You can debug javascript in browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/DiemDanh/testMethod',
    data: { info: JSON.stringify(ngay) },
    type: "POST",
    traditional:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('running');
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }
});
}
```

Comment: Open browser developer tools(ctrl+shift+I) and select network tab when you get 500 internal server error. You can click your error link can see details error

Answer (score 0):

change your method parameter with string multi dimensional array it will work because list of list strings parameter won't work it'll not accepting 2d array

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult testMethod(string [][] info)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: it's still error. Are you have another way send 2d array to controller?